# is there a difference between running an executable and debugging it in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, runtime-error, visual-studio-debugging

I'm writing a piece of code in Windows which uses both winapi messagebox and some dynamic memory for RS232 application

I saw a strange situation when the same application creates different error when I run it in debugging mode (using VS2010 and step-in debugging) and running it as an executable in command-line

in first case, the error is popped up properly with a winapi messagebox and the program returns/ends properly. Second case, it creates run-time error and also the memory leak

Is there such difference between these two run modes? and how to catch winapi run-time error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are differences between Debug builds and Release builds. The behavior of a program is also sometimes different, when run under a debugger (regardless of configuration), and running as an isolated process. With the information provided, it is impossible to answer your question, though. General advice: Learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Running a program directly form the debugger the debug heap is in use. Assuming it isn't compiled in debug mode.
And the memory layout changes when the debugger is loaded into the process address space. So some weird things may happen.

If you have such strange effects it is sometimes better to attach the debugger to the running process.

Comment: since I cannot see the error in debug mode, so I don't even know where it comes from. But the error appears in isolated run mode. I think there should be a way to catch this run-time error. I actually tried std error catching but shows nothing

Comment: @Shawn: You can debug a Release build as well. Set up your debugger to break, when a Win32 exception is **thrown**. You'll have the entire callstack at the time of the error available.

Comment: @llnspectable: thanks for your advice! I tried it and it's really interesting that debugging in release mode, it actually shows each line in computer low level code, though I don't have any sense in them by now. It is, I think, a heap corruption error, I may post the link here http://pastebin.com/88whGizh

Comment: the error line is "775B3B65  int         3" , hope you can give me some further hints about this error @llnspectable

Comment: @Shawn: Hint: Learn how to use a debugger. If you don't know what a callstack is, you'll be forced to write perfect code for the rest of your life. Since that is not going to happen, you'll have to learn how to use a debugger. It's the tool you'll be using more frequently than anything else.

Comment: @llnspectable: In case you insist I think I should close the topic by now. I really learnt much from this error. Still, it will take a way around to solve current project error

Comment: The debug heap is in use for any Debug configuration (with default settings). It can be controlled through an environment variable ([_NO_DEBUG_HEAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545528.aspx)). Attaching a debugger doesn't make a difference. Since the debug engine is part of the OS, no additional modules are loaded either, and the memory layout doesn't change. [WaitForDebugEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681423.aspx) is a kernel32.dll export, for example.